# FakeLocation Tweak (Via Cydia) has shut down my iPad and it doesn't want to work

Tags: ios, jailbreak, crash, tweaks

I downloaded a tweak via Cydia called FakeLocation. Once I downloaded it my iPad couldn't open again even if I charge it. Tried connecting it to iTunes on my PC to restore it but it doesn't want to connect because there's no battery. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn it off and charge it with your wall charger.

Then boot it into DFU mode and restore it with iTunes.

Comment: i can't it's out of battery and if i tried to charge it. the boot logo will disappear and the Empty battery will show up again wich means it can't be used at all.

Comment: No problem! @UltimaXIV :)

Answer (score 2):

You can boot into Substrate Safe Mode by **holding the volume up button on boot**. This disables tweaks such as this which should let you get back in to the device and back in to Cydia to uninstall it.